# Give a function $f(x)$ sucht that the given power series is the Taylor series of $f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

I always have trouble with this question:

Give a function $f(x)$ sucht that the given power series is the Taylor series of $f(x)$.

For example $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ((n+\frac{1}{n})x^n)$, or $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n+1}x^n)$.

Is there a standard way to determine $f(x)$?Or standard steps you can try to find $f(x)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the first one, do you mean $\sum_n (n+\frac1n)x^n$? Otherwise it's not even a power series.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah I did, sorry just forgot the ()

Comment: Look for "generating function"

Answer (score 2):

First of all, an universal answer to the problem of knowing a function such that its Taylor series is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ (assuming that the radius of convergence $R$ of the series is not $0$) is $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ ($|x|<R$).

But there are tricks to find better answers. For instance, in the case of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(n+\frac1n\right)x^n$, you can break it in two: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$. The second one is $\log(1-x)$. The first one is$$x\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=x\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\right)'=x\left(\frac x{1-x}\right)'=\frac x{(1-x)^2}.$$

Now, let us take $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n+1}$. Then $$xf(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=\log(1-x).$$ Therefore,$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{\log(1-x)}x&\text{ if }0<|x|<1\\ 1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a "standard way" as much as there's a collection of tricks that sometimes work, and then having enough experience to be able to guess at which tricks could work in a particular case.

For $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{n+1}x^n$ the main trick is *termwise differentiation*. If we multiply the function by $x$ we get
$$ x f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1} $$
where the coefficients disappear when we differentiate, so
$$ \frac{d}{dx}(x f(x)) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n $$
The right-hand side is a geometric series which you hopefully know how to sum. Then you can integrate both sides, giving you an expression for $x f(x)$, and divide by $x$. Finally, at this point you can adjust the constant of integration such that $f(0)$ has the right value (namely the constant term of the series you started out with).

---

For $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+\frac1n)x^n$ you would split it into $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n x^n$. The latter of these can be handled the same as before; for the former we can turn it around and *integrate* term for term. We get
$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n \\
\frac{g(x)}{x} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} \\
\int \frac{g(x)}{x} dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n $$
and after applying the rule for a geometric series (again) you just have to *differentiate* each side symbolically and multiply by $x$.